# Keys not being sent for first two fields in modal

Tags: java, c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Okay, so the process of the automation is:

1. Click Add Address Button. Modal appears but not finished loading
2. Wait for all fields and buttons to load using wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xPath)).
3. Send keys
4. Select Save Recipient Button

However, there are a few instances where the first two keys are not sent. I have tried waiting for the modal but keys are less likely to send.
Am I using the wrong wait.until parameter? Am I waiting for the wrong element? I am assuming there is some race case condition happening right now

Comment: Is the xPath on the textbox or the Modal?

Comment: currently on each field (10) and buttons. Before I had it on the xpath of the submit button, which is at the bottom of the field, xpath of the last field, and the the xpath of the modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static class WebDriverExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Try finding the element for timeoutInSeconds until throwing "no matching element"
    /// </summary>
    public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
    {
        if (timeoutInSeconds <= 0) return driver.FindElement(@by);

        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
        return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(@by));
    }
}
```

Then you can call this

```
driver.FindElements(By.xpath(xPath),5).SendKeys(fieldOneString);
```

Where xPath is for fieldOne

Comment: Sounds good. I'll implement this in Java and get back to you in a few hours.